# How can I change camera image details (metadata)?

Tags: image-processing, photoshop

I want to make my photo editing like a snapshot of my smartphone's camera, but when I check it can't.

When I edit it in Photoshop, the image details become Photoshop, so how can I set it so that the details become the camera of my smartphone?

[image: detail image my smartphone and edit photoshop]

Answer (score 0):

> digiKam incorporates a fast Image Editor with many image editing tools. 
>    You can use the Image Editor to view your photographs, comment and rate
>    them, correct, enhance and alter them. The editing power can be easily
>    extended by a set of plugins, the KDE Image Plugins Interface (manual)
>    While digiKam remains easy to use, it provides professional level features
>    by the dozens. It is fully 16 bit enabled including all available plugins,
>    supports RAW format conversion through libraw, DNG export and ICC color
>    management work flow.
>    digiKam can also make use of the KIPI image handling plugins to
>    extend its capabilities even further for photo manipulations,
>    import and export, etc. The kipi-plugins package contains many
>    very useful extensions.

First of all nstall digikam using

```
sudo apt install digikam
```

#### To edit details or metadata of image:

- Open digiKam and add the folder as Album by clicking on  *Album→New*

  [image]
- Then click on the desired image and go to *Tools→Image Editor*

  [image]
- A new dialog will be opened with all editing options for the image. In order to edit the details/metadata, click on *Tools→Edit Metadata*

  [image]
- Again a new window will popup like below. There you can edit all details such as EXIF, IPTC, and XMP.

  [image]